# Update UI with a client component after a server action NEXT JS

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I'm new to NEXT JS and I'm trying to understand the logic behind the client component and server component.

I've understood the new server action functions that would be very useful in my project

I currently have a form (client component) with attached a server action that fetches data from an external API.

```
"use client";

import { useFormState } from "react-dom";
import { requestImg } from "@/actions/formActions";

export default function Form() {
  const [state, formAction] = useFormState(requestImg, {
    error: "",
    success: false,
    data: {},
  });

  const { error, success, data } = state;
  console.log(error);

  return (
    <form
      className="bg-slate-100 p-8 rounded shadow-md max-w-md w-full mx-4"
      action={formAction}
    > ... OTHER STUFF
```

The idea is that after the server action returns with the data fetched, **I should show a new page or, even better, a Modal that shows the new data and, lets me, again, execute another server action based on the data**, fetched before from the server nation, chosen.

I was able to get the first round trip, with the new data fetched from the first server action but I've now idea how to make it appear the Modal with the new data being interactive.

#### server action below

```
export const requestImg = async (prevState: any, formData: FormData) => {
  const link = formData.get("link");

  const response = await fetch(
    `https://<my API>/get-all-images/`,
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        link_post: link,
      }),
    }
  );
  const result = await response.json();

  revalidatePath("/");

  if (result.status != 403 && result.status != 404 && result.status != 500) {
    return { error: "", success: true, data: result };
  } else {
    return { error: "Error " + result.status, success: false, data: {} };
  }
};
```

I thought about [cookies](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies) being saved from the first server action so, the second can read them and start from there but I don't know if it's the right path